# urllib.unquote_plus gives a different output on the same string

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib, urlencode, python-unicode

I'm a bit of a python noob and having problems understanding what's happening here. I'm decoding a URL encoded string. I have a file `dump®.txt` (the leading space is there on purpose). When I change my object type, I get two different results:

```
>>> string1 = u'+dump%C2%AE.txt'
>>> print urllib.unquote_plus(string1)
 dumpÂ®.txt

>>> string2 = '+dump%C2%AE.txt'
>>> print urllib.unquote_plus(string2)
 dump®.txt
```

I was expecting was to see only the `®` character for `string1` and `string2` (or maybe even the reverse behavior). Can anyone help me understand why is it that `string1` needs to be a string type before I get my desired `dump®.txt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anyone help me understand why is it that `string1` needs to be a string type before I get my desired `dump®.txt`?

`urllib` does not support unicode, because urls can contain ASCII characters, by definition.  There is some [crappy code in Python 2](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c02307e9634583d3f2660e46b5200bf0b282695a/Lib/urllib.py#L1222-L1231) that tries to do the right thing if you pass a unicode object, and it's buggy.

Passing a unicode object to `urllib.unquote` is user error - don't do that.  This is correct:

```
print urllib.unquote_plus(string1.encode())
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly the disclaimer I was hoping for in the urllib docs but couldn't track down.

Comment: In Python 3, though, all strings are unicode by default, and `urllib.parse.unquote()` acts properly on them. Right?

Comment: Right - this is just a Python 2 problem.